# NVIDIA login loop and console login issues

Tags: nvidia, login, console

I have issues with the Nvidia login loop. Logging in makes the screen go black and I am redirected back to the login page. I have found other posts that will help with the Nividia login loop, but my main issue is not being about to login via the console.

When I try to login via the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) I get the message of the day, then it asks me to login again. I haven't been able to find a way to get around this, everything I find involves getting past this point.

I confirmed I was entering the correct credentials. If I entered incorrect credentials I get an error saying so. The message of the day only appears when I enter the correct credentials.

Comment: are You using laptop with nvidia optimus technology?

Comment: I am not. I am using a pc that is dual booted with Ubuntu.

Comment: I was stuck on my Debian Stretch once, accidently used `nvidia-xconfig` which generated `xorg.conf` in `/etc/X11/`. After reboot i had infinite login loop. `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf` and `sudo reboot` fixed that for me. If You wanna try it, bacup Your xorg.conf.

Comment: I am willing to give it a try. But I do not think I will be able to do that without first solving the console login issues. I could login as a guest but, of course, I won't have admin privileges.

Not sure if it is worth mentioning. But the last thing in the message of the day dialog is the number of packages that can be updated, some of which are security related.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: The Nvidia loop part of my issue is most definitely, but I can't complete the first step of that solution (login with Ctrl + Alt + F1).
I haven't been able to find anything that talks about what to do if you can't even log in via console